# Issue with running CSS transition with another element's hover

Tags: html, css

I'm attempting to create a menu that I can use for a website.
I have a nice little graphic for the menu button in the top left corner, and it works when you hover over the bars themselves.
Why is the transition not running while the mouse is hovering over the menu but does when the mouse is over the bars?

css --

```
      .bars:hover .line-top { transform: translateY(9px)      rotateZ(45deg); }
      .bars:hover .line-middle { transform: rotateZ(135deg); }
      .bars:hover .line-bottom { transform: translateY(-9px)      rotateZ(135deg); }

      .menu-holder:hover ~ .bars .line-top { transform:       translateY(9px) rotateZ(45deg); }
      .menu-holder:hover ~ .bars .line-middle { transform:      rotateZ(135deg); }
      .menu-holder:hover ~ .bars .line-bottom { transform:      translateY(-9px) rotateZ(135deg); }

      .menu-holder {
        width: 200px;
        position: absolute;
        top: 0;
        left: -150px;
        height: 100vh;
        background: red;
        transition: transform 1s;
      }

      .bars:hover ~ .menu-holder{
        transform: translateX(150px);
      }
      .menu-holder:hover {
        transform: translateX(150px);
      }

      .line-top, .line-middle, .line-bottom {
        width: 30px;
        height: 8px;
        border-radius: 28px;
        background: black;
        margin: 1px;
        transition: transform 1s;
      }

      .bars {
        width: 30px;
        z-index: 2;
        position: absolute;
      }
```

html --

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  </head>
  <body>
    
    <div class="bars">
      <div class="line-top"></div>
      <div class="line-middle"></div>
      <div class="line-bottom"></div>
    </div>

    <div class="menu-holder slider">
    </div>

    <!-- <script src="script.js"></script> -->
  </body>
</html>
```

P.S. I'm very new to CSS and it may just be a simple mistake

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CSS selectors go in one direction. `.a ~ .b` means "every `.b` element after `.a` elements will have the subsequent properties applied to said `.b` elements". So, your `.menu-holder:hover ~ .bars` has no effect, as there are no elements with class `bars` after your `menu-holder` element.